# Office Add-in Taskpane can't find html file

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Developing an office web add-in for Outlook. I Followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) to start my project.

I tried implementing a new taskpane, but when I open it I get this error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

When I try to access de sideloading at `https://localhost:3000/src/taskpane/taskpane.html`, the page is only containing `Cannot GET /src/taskpane/taskpane.html`.

I have no error in the manifest and I updated the `webpack.config.js` with:

```
entry: {
  polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
  taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.js"
}


new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: "taskpane.html",
    template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
    chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"]
  })
```

I don't know what I'm missing, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem, I was doing almost everything right. I was typing the full path, but I only needed to specify the filename like this: `https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html`